# Issue running runnable Jar packaged using Maven plugin with Spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have created a runnable jar using maven assembly plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.loaders.FundLoader</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have some Spring dependencies packaged into the jar.
When I run the program using intellIj the program runs perfectly fine.
However when I run the program from the command line using: java -jar myjar.jar
I got the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefiniti
onStoreException: Line 6 in XML document from class path resource [spring/loader-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptio
n; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 120; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of e
lement 'beans'.

Attached my config file: loader-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:hibernate.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.driver.class.name}" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.password}" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
</bean>



 </beans>
```

And then the content of my pom.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.operations</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>loader</artifactId>
<name>[FOR] loader</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.loaders.FundLoader</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>




<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Could someone please help me out ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring applications cannot be simly packaged as a fat JAR with the `maven-assembly-plugin`, for each Spring module JAR has its schemas located in a file that is always at the same location (`META-INF/spring.schemas`).

When you flatten all your dependencies in one final JAR, you will obviously only has one of these `spring.schemas` files in your resulting JAR, hence your issue.

I would suggest to either use [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) for developing your application, as it includes a plugin that deals nicely with Spring JARs.

Or you can also use [onejar-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/), which also packages the fat JAR in a specific way that avoids having this issue.

Other solutions also exists, such as the [maven-shade-plugin and its AppendingTransformer](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer)

You can even provide merged versions of the problematic files by yourself, as project resources, and then excluding the originals from being assembled.

Comment: That isn't true, you can package it perfectly as a single jar,you can even use the `maven-shade-plugin` you have to take care of merging all the different `spring.schema` and `spring.handlers`  into a single large file. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer

Comment: I don't know if you can package or not as a single war, but the onejar-maven-plugin proposed by Tome worked like a charm. So I give the answer as Valid. Thanks Tome!

Comment: @M. Deinum, indeed, the `maven-shade-plugin` also provides a way to do that, I'll add it to the response. I find it more easy with nested JARs structure, as with this, you don't have to know about everything that has to be merged.

Comment: This answer is nice but it really should be changed from saying that this cannot be done, as it clearly *can* be done and you've also mentioned ways to do it yourself.